# Duplicate Save and Cancel buttons Document Library Edit Properties

Tags: document-library, content-type

I have duplicate edit and save buttons when I edit properties of a document in a document library.

I copied this site from another using Manage Content and Structure.

The original site did not have this problem.

I am using custom content types from a content hub.

Any ideas what causes this?

Thanks,
Ric

Answer (score 0):

I have seen duplicate sets of buttons in custom forms created with SharePoint Designer. Try opening the library with SPD, create new Edit and New forms. Make these the default forms.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up with triplicate sets of Save and Cancel buttons in the Create new folder form after an append import of a library.

The import log showed an error on the upload.aspx form and we noticed that the `upload.aspx` contains a duplicate web part definition of PAGE_NEWFORM. By removing the latter definition and saving the Create new folder form was restored to normal.